# Rounding to 2 decimals

Tags: sql, rounding

Below is the code I currently using which I need to round the end result to 2 decimals. I am assuming that I have too many, too few, or in the wrong place when it comes to the "()" and my eyes are bleeding from trying to break it down and rebuild it. Can someone help me figure out what I did wrong.

```
,Round((((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)*.75)+
      (Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.CreditIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end)*.4))/Nullif(Count(Distinct(S.GamingDate)),0)),2) as ADL
```

Comment: Too many and too few can simple be solved by counting. Apart from that, you should get a syntax error too if they don't match. Did you get an error?

Comment: have you tried just casting the result to a decimal like CAST({your result} as DECIMAL(18,2)) that should then round it automatically for you

Comment: You can remove the parentheses around both the sums, and the ones around `S.GamingDate`. But they don't *have* to be removed. Also, it seems the parentheses are right in numbers and position.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cast it as a decimal instead of rounding:

```
CAST((((Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Slot' then S.CashIn - S.CashOut - S.JackPot Else 0 end)*.75)+
  (Sum(case when S.StatType = 'Pit' then S.CashIn + S.CreditIn + S.ChipsIn + S.FrontIn - S.CashOut Else 0 end)*.4))/Nullif(Count(Distinct(S.GamingDate)),0)) AS DECIMAL(18,2)) as ADL
```

Comment: Arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric. Got this error when trying to use your code good sir.

Comment: However when I changed it from (4,2) to (18,2) like David Shorthose suggested it worked just fine. I have not use this before will need to look more into this Cast as Decimal thing.

Comment: Make sure the AS DECIMAL(4,2) is set to the proper length for your need.  I just made an edit and increased it to 18, but i'm not sure how long you need it to be.